# Getting Input for an Array of Structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I would like to obtain name and score pairs for an array of structs. One field in the struct is a c-string and I am not sure how to store input in the form of a string in that field. When I run the following code the "score" field is stored correctly but after I input a string for scores[counter].name the console window does not accept anymore input. the cursor simply blinks without anything happening. Can someone tell me what is going on? Thank you!

```
struct highscore
{
    int score;
    char name[charSize];
};

void initializeData(highscore scores[], int size)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name for score #" << (counter + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> scores[counter].score;
        cout << "Enter the score for score #" << (counter + 1) << ": ";
        do {
            cin >> scores[counter].name;
        } while (scores[counter].name != '\0');
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have the input of `score` and `name` switched. This probably puts the input stream into the fail state when the given name can't be converted to an integer. When in a fail state input streams reject further input until the error is [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)ed (and you probably want to remove the offending input or it'll be parsed again and fail again).

Comment: Unrelated: consider using `std::string` instead of the `char` array for `name.

Comment: Ahh, easy fix. Cheers!

Comment: I guess you should use std::string instead of an array of characters..Simple is better than complex.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle strings (a long sequence of characters) or even the strings that have spaces just use the following library in C++.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

Then just declare a string variable.

```
struct highscore
{
    int score;
    String name;
};
```

Then in your loop,

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name for score #" << (counter + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> scores[counter].name;
        cout << "Enter the score for score #" << (counter + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> scores[counter].score;
    }
```